# Silent exception,

Tags: c#, exception, 64-bit

I've encountered this weird issue of silent exceptions in 64 bit.
What is that cause this bahavior?
I would like to understand why does this occur and what is the recommended solution?

- [disappearing OnLoad exception](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/)
- [microsoft - silent exception](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/357311/silent-exceptions-on-x64-development-machines)
- [KB976038](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976038)

on the main:

```
    try
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    catch
        (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("oh no!");
}
```

Comment: `Unfortunately where is nothing that the Visual Studo team can do to address this, it is the result of operating system design. All feedback regarding this issue should be addressed to the Windows team; however the Windows team considers this to be the "correct" operating system design, and considers the x86 behavior to be "incorrect"` Haha. Nice Microsoft. *Please contact the other team about this, but they won't fix it because they think that the third team have implemented it incorrectly.*

Comment: Actually that second article is a quite nice and in-depth explanation both of the problem and the solution.

Comment: Apparently there is a hotfix (linked to in the link you provide).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to load a form, your code will call into a kernel function to create the form's window, and this kernel function will in turn call back into your code by sending a message that invokes your `OnLoad` method. If you throw an exception in that method, the exception handling mechanism walks the call stack back to the kernel mode boundary.

On x86 an exception can go through this boundary and back to the original caller. On x64 it stops when it hits the boundary and cannot continue. In XP64 and Vista the exception was swallowed (ignored), while a 64-bit app with a manifest saying it is Win7-compatible will crash when this happens. To get the crashing behavior on other OSes or for 32-bit apps on 64-bit Win7, see [KB976038](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976038).

This behavior will happen for any event handler that is invoked as a callback from kernel mode on x64.

Comment: user271077: It's complicated :)  Read the first link at the top of the page for all the details